# Automatically align text in UILabel according to text language

Tags: objective-c, ios6, localization, alignment, right-to-left

I'm interested in setting some text into a `UILabel`, and depending on the directionality of the language (e.g., Hebrew - right-to-left [RTL], English - left-to-right [LTR]) set the alignment of the `UILabel`.

Note that using iOS 6's `NSTextAlignmentNatural` does not solve the problem, as it chooses alignment according to the current locale, experiments show.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ended up following the advice [given in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636974/1071136): write a short script that will parse the Unicode data [publicly available here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt), and generate code to identify whether a code-point has a strong R or AL directionality attribute.  Then, the string is searched for the first such character.
This is exactly what [ubidi_getBaseDirection](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubidi_8h.html#aeb1fd15743833278cc11906cd5a48aef) from the ICU package does.

Since the internal representation of `NSString` is UTF16 (which is a variable-length encoding), it is first converted to UTF32 in order to simplify the scanning code. An alternative approach would be to decode the string on the fly, which requires dealing with BOM and Unicode surrogates. Yet another approach is simply ignoring characters not representable by one `unichar`. For more details, see [Wikipedia's UTF16 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

## Short Answer

```
@interface NSString (TextDirectionality)

/* Return 1 if the string is strongly LTR, -1 if strongly RTL, or 0 if neutral. */
/* See http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubidi_8h.html#aeb1fd15743833278cc11906cd5a48aef */
-(int)getBaseDirection;

@end

@implementation NSString (TextDirectionality)

// Function takes UTF32 character, and not a unichar (=UTF16 character),
// because some Unicode characters need full 32 bits to represent.
BOOL isCodePointStrongRTL(UTF32Char c) {
  return ((c == 0x5BE) || (c == 0x5C0) || (c == 0x5C3) || (c == 0x5C6) || (c >= 0x5D0 && c <= 0x5EA) || (c >= 0x5F0 && c <= 0x5F4) || (c == 0x608) || (c == 0x60B) || (c == 0x60D) || (c == 0x61B) || (c >= 0x61E && c <= 0x64A) || (c >= 0x66D && c <= 0x66F) || (c >= 0x671 && c <= 0x6D5) || (c >= 0x6E5 && c <= 0x6E6) || (c >= 0x6EE && c <= 0x6EF) || (c >= 0x6FA && c <= 0x70D) || (c >= 0x70F && c <= 0x710) || (c >= 0x712 && c <= 0x72F) || (c >= 0x74D && c <= 0x7A5) || (c == 0x7B1) || (c >= 0x7C0 && c <= 0x7EA) || (c >= 0x7F4 && c <= 0x7F5) || (c == 0x7FA) || (c >= 0x800 && c <= 0x815) || (c == 0x81A) || (c == 0x824) || (c == 0x828) || (c >= 0x830 && c <= 0x83E) || (c >= 0x840 && c <= 0x858) || (c == 0x85E) || (c == 0x8A0) || (c >= 0x8A2 && c <= 0x8AC) || (c == 0x200F) || (c == 0xFB1D) || (c >= 0xFB1F && c <= 0xFB28) || (c >= 0xFB2A && c <= 0xFB36) || (c >= 0xFB38 && c <= 0xFB3C) || (c == 0xFB3E) || (c >= 0xFB40 && c <= 0xFB41) || (c >= 0xFB43 && c <= 0xFB44) || (c >= 0xFB46 && c <= 0xFBC1) || (c >= 0xFBD3 && c <= 0xFD3D) || (c >= 0xFD50 && c <= 0xFD8F) || (c >= 0xFD92 && c <= 0xFDC7) || (c >= 0xFDF0 && c <= 0xFDFC) || (c >= 0xFE70 && c <= 0xFE74) || (c >= 0xFE76 && c <= 0xFEFC) || (c >= 0x10800 && c <= 0x10805) || (c == 0x10808) || (c >= 0x1080A && c <= 0x10835) || (c >= 0x10837 && c <= 0x10838) || (c == 0x1083C) || (c >= 0x1083F && c <= 0x10855) || (c >= 0x10857 && c <= 0x1085F) || (c >= 0x10900 && c <= 0x1091B) || (c >= 0x10920 && c <= 0x10939) || (c == 0x1093F) || (c >= 0x10980 && c <= 0x109B7) || (c >= 0x109BE && c <= 0x109BF) || (c == 0x10A00) || (c >= 0x10A10 && c <= 0x10A13) || (c >= 0x10A15 && c <= 0x10A17) || (c >= 0x10A19 && c <= 0x10A33) || (c >= 0x10A40 && c <= 0x10A47) || (c >= 0x10A50 && c <= 0x10A58) || (c >= 0x10A60 && c <= 0x10A7F) || (c >= 0x10B00 && c <= 0x10B35) || (c >= 0x10B40 && c <= 0x10B55) || (c >= 0x10B58 && c <= 0x10B72) || (c >= 0x10B78 && c <= 0x10B7F) || (c >= 0x10C00 && c <= 0x10C48) || (c >= 0x1EE00 && c <= 0x1EE03) || (c >= 0x1EE05 && c <= 0x1EE1F) || (c >= 0x1EE21 && c <= 0x1EE22) || (c == 0x1EE24) || (c == 0x1EE27) || (c >= 0x1EE29 && c <= 0x1EE32) || (c >= 0x1EE34 && c <= 0x1EE37) || (c == 0x1EE39) || (c == 0x1EE3B) || (c == 0x1EE42) || (c == 0x1EE47) || (c == 0x1EE49) || (c == 0x1EE4B) || (c >= 0x1EE4D && c <= 0x1EE4F) || (c >= 0x1EE51 && c <= 0x1EE52) || (c == 0x1EE54) || (c == 0x1EE57) || (c == 0x1EE59) || (c == 0x1EE5B) || (c == 0x1EE5D) || (c == 0x1EE5F) || (c >= 0x1EE61 && c <= 0x1EE62) || (c == 0x1EE64) || (c >= 0x1EE67 && c <= 0x1EE6A) || (c >= 0x1EE6C && c <= 0x1EE72) || (c >= 0x1EE74 && c <= 0x1EE77) || (c >= 0x1EE79 && c <= 0x1EE7C) || (c == 0x1EE7E) || (c >= 0x1EE80 && c <= 0x1EE89) || (c >= 0x1EE8B && c <= 0x1EE9B) || (c >= 0x1EEA1 && c <= 0x1EEA3) || (c >= 0x1EEA5 && c <= 0x1EEA9) || (c >= 0x1EEAB && c <= 0x1EEBB));
}

BOOL isCodePointStrongLTR(UTF32Char c) {
  return (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A) || (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7A) || (c == 0xAA) || (c == 0xB5) || (c == 0xBA) || (c >= 0xC0 && c <= 0xD6) || (c >= 0xD8 && c <= 0xF6) || (c >= 0xF8 && c <= 0x2B8) || (c >= 0x2BB && c <= 0x2C1) || (c >= 0x2D0 && c <= 0x2D1) || (c >= 0x2E0 && c <= 0x2E4) || (c == 0x2EE) || (c >= 0x370 && c <= 0x373) || (c >= 0x376 && c <= 0x377) || (c >= 0x37A && c <= 0x37D) || (c == 0x386) || (c >= 0x388 && c <= 0x38A) || (c == 0x38C) || (c >= 0x38E && c <= 0x3A1) || (c >= 0x3A3 && c <= 0x3F5) || (c >= 0x3F7 && c <= 0x482) || (c >= 0x48A && c <= 0x527) || (c >= 0x531 && c <= 0x556) || (c >= 0x559 && c <= 0x55F) || (c >= 0x561 && c <= 0x587) || (c == 0x589) || (c >= 0x903 && c <= 0x939) || (c == 0x93B) || (c >= 0x93D && c <= 0x940) || (c >= 0x949 && c <= 0x94C) || (c >= 0x94E && c <= 0x950) || (c >= 0x958 && c <= 0x961) || (c >= 0x964 && c <= 0x977) || (c >= 0x979 && c <= 0x97F) || (c >= 0x982 && c <= 0x983) || (c >= 0x985 && c <= 0x98C) || (c >= 0x98F && c <= 0x990) || (c >= 0x993 && c <= 0x9A8) || (c >= 0x9AA && c <= 0x9B0) || (c == 0x9B2) || (c >= 0x9B6 && c <= 0x9B9) || (c >= 0x9BD && c <= 0x9C0) || (c >= 0x9C7 && c <= 0x9C8) || (c >= 0x9CB && c <= 0x9CC) || (c == 0x9CE) || (c == 0x9D7) || (c >= 0x9DC && c <= 0x9DD) || (c >= 0x9DF && c <= 0x9E1) || (c >= 0x9E6 && c <= 0x9F1) || (c >= 0x9F4 && c <= 0x9FA) || (c == 0xA03) || (c >= 0xA05 && c <= 0xA0A) || (c >= 0xA0F && c <= 0xA10) || (c >= 0xA13 && c <= 0xA28) || (c >= 0xA2A && c <= 0xA30) || (c >= 0xA32 && c <= 0xA33) || (c >= 0xA35 && c <= 0xA36) || (c >= 0xA38 && c <= 0xA39) || (c >= 0xA3E && c <= 0xA40) || (c >= 0xA59 && c <= 0xA5C) || (c == 0xA5E) || (c >= 0xA66 && c <= 0xA6F) || (c >= 0xA72 && c <= 0xA74) || (c == 0xA83) || (c >= 0xA85 && c <= 0xA8D) || (c >= 0xA8F && c <= 0xA91) || (c >= 0xA93 && c <= 0xAA8) || (c >= 0xAAA && c <= 0xAB0) || (c >= 0xAB2 && c <= 0xAB3) || (c >= 0xAB5 && c <= 0xAB9) || (c >= 0xABD && c <= 0xAC0) || (c == 0xAC9) || (c >= 0xACB && c <= 0xACC) || (c == 0xAD0) || (c >= 0xAE0 && c <= 0xAE1) || (c >= 0xAE6 && c <= 0xAF0) || (c >= 0xB02 && c <= 0xB03) || (c >= 0xB05 && c <= 0xB0C) || (c >= 0xB0F && c <= 0xB10) || (c >= 0xB13 && c <= 0xB28) || (c >= 0xB2A && c <= 0xB30) || (c >= 0xB32 && c <= 0xB33) || (c >= 0xB35 && c <= 0xB39) || (c >= 0xB3D && c <= 0xB3E) || (c == 0xB40) || (c >= 0xB47 && c <= 0xB48) || (c >= 0xB4B && c <= 0xB4C) || (c == 0xB57) || (c >= 0xB5C && c <= 0xB5D) || (c >= 0xB5F && c <= 0xB61) || (c >= 0xB66 && c <= 0xB77) || (c == 0xB83) || (c >= 0xB85 && c <= 0xB8A) || (c >= 0xB8E && c <= 0xB90) || (c >= 0xB92 && c <= 0xB95) || (c >= 0xB99 && c <= 0xB9A) || (c == 0xB9C) || (c >= 0xB9E && c <= 0xB9F) || (c >= 0xBA3 && c <= 0xBA4) || (c >= 0xBA8 && c <= 0xBAA) || (c >= 0xBAE && c <= 0xBB9) || (c >= 0xBBE && c <= 0xBBF) || (c >= 0xBC1 && c <= 0xBC2) || (c >= 0xBC6 && c <= 0xBC8) || (c >= 0xBCA && c <= 0xBCC) || (c == 0xBD0) || (c == 0xBD7) || (c >= 0xBE6 && c <= 0xBF2) || (c >= 0xC01 && c <= 0xC03) || (c >= 0xC05 && c <= 0xC0C) || (c >= 0xC0E && c <= 0xC10) || (c >= 0xC12 && c <= 0xC28) || (c >= 0xC2A && c <= 0xC33) || (c >= 0xC35 && c <= 0xC39) || (c == 0xC3D) || (c >= 0xC41 && c <= 0xC44) || (c >= 0xC58 && c <= 0xC59) || (c >= 0xC60 && c <= 0xC61) || (c >= 0xC66 && c <= 0xC6F) || (c == 0xC7F) || (c >= 0xC82 && c <= 0xC83) || (c >= 0xC85 && c <= 0xC8C) || (c >= 0xC8E && c <= 0xC90) || (c >= 0xC92 && c <= 0xCA8) || (c >= 0xCAA && c <= 0xCB3) || (c >= 0xCB5 && c <= 0xCB9) || (c >= 0xCBD && c <= 0xCC4) || (c >= 0xCC6 && c <= 0xCC8) || (c >= 0xCCA && c <= 0xCCB) || (c >= 0xCD5 && c <= 0xCD6) || (c == 0xCDE) || (c >= 0xCE0 && c <= 0xCE1) || (c >= 0xCE6 && c <= 0xCEF) || (c >= 0xCF1 && c <= 0xCF2) || (c >= 0xD02 && c <= 0xD03) || (c >= 0xD05 && c <= 0xD0C) || (c >= 0xD0E && c <= 0xD10) || (c >= 0xD12 && c <= 0xD3A) || (c >= 0xD3D && c <= 0xD40) || (c >= 0xD46 && c <= 0xD48) || (c >= 0xD4A && c <= 0xD4C) || (c == 0xD4E) || (c == 0xD57) || (c >= 0xD60 && c <= 0xD61) || (c >= 0xD66 && c <= 0xD75) || (c >= 0xD79 && c <= 0xD7F) || (c >= 0xD82 && c <= 0xD83) || (c >= 0xD85 && c <= 0xD96) || (c >= 0xD9A && c <= 0xDB1) || (c >= 0xDB3 && c <= 0xDBB) || (c == 0xDBD) || (c >= 0xDC0 && c <= 0xDC6) || (c >= 0xDCF && c <= 0xDD1) || (c >= 0xDD8 && c <= 0xDDF) || (c >= 0xDF2 && c <= 0xDF4) || (c >= 0xE01 && c <= 0xE30) || (c >= 0xE32 && c <= 0xE33) || (c >= 0xE40 && c <= 0xE46) || (c >= 0xE4F && c <= 0xE5B) || (c >= 0xE81 && c <= 0xE82) || (c == 0xE84) || (c >= 0xE87 && c <= 0xE88) || (c == 0xE8A) || (c == 0xE8D) || (c >= 0xE94 && c <= 0xE97) || (c >= 0xE99 && c <= 0xE9F) || (c >= 0xEA1 && c <= 0xEA3) || (c == 0xEA5) || (c == 0xEA7) || (c >= 0xEAA && c <= 0xEAB) || (c >= 0xEAD && c <= 0xEB0) || (c >= 0xEB2 && c <= 0xEB3) || (c == 0xEBD) || (c >= 0xEC0 && c <= 0xEC4) || (c == 0xEC6) || (c >= 0xED0 && c <= 0xED9) || (c >= 0xEDC && c <= 0xEDF) || (c >= 0xF00 && c <= 0xF17) || (c >= 0xF1A && c <= 0xF34) || (c == 0xF36) || (c == 0xF38) || (c >= 0xF3E && c <= 0xF47) || (c >= 0xF49 && c <= 0xF6C) || (c == 0xF7F) || (c == 0xF85) || (c >= 0xF88 && c <= 0xF8C) || (c >= 0xFBE && c <= 0xFC5) || (c >= 0xFC7 && c <= 0xFCC) || (c >= 0xFCE && c <= 0xFDA) || (c >= 0x1000 && c <= 0x102C) || (c == 0x1031) || (c == 0x1038) || (c >= 0x103B && c <= 0x103C) || (c >= 0x103F && c <= 0x1057) || (c >= 0x105A && c <= 0x105D) || (c >= 0x1061 && c <= 0x1070) || (c >= 0x1075 && c <= 0x1081) || (c >= 0x1083 && c <= 0x1084) || (c >= 0x1087 && c <= 0x108C) || (c >= 0x108E && c <= 0x109C) || (c >= 0x109E && c <= 0x10C5) || (c == 0x10C7) || (c == 0x10CD) || (c >= 0x10D0 && c <= 0x1248) || (c >= 0x124A && c <= 0x124D) || (c >= 0x1250 && c <= 0x1256) || (c == 0x1258) || (c >= 0x125A && c <= 0x125D) || (c >= 0x1260 && c <= 0x1288) || (c >= 0x128A && c <= 0x128D) || (c >= 0x1290 && c <= 0x12B0) || (c >= 0x12B2 && c <= 0x12B5) || (c >= 0x12B8 && c <= 0x12BE) || (c == 0x12C0) || (c >= 0x12C2 && c <= 0x12C5) || (c >= 0x12C8 && c <= 0x12D6) || (c >= 0x12D8 && c <= 0x1310) || (c >= 0x1312 && c <= 0x1315) || (c >= 0x1318 && c <= 0x135A) || (c >= 0x1360 && c <= 0x137C) || (c >= 0x1380 && c <= 0x138F) || (c >= 0x13A0 && c <= 0x13F4) || (c >= 0x1401 && c <= 0x167F) || (c >= 0x1681 && c <= 0x169A) || (c >= 0x16A0 && c <= 0x16F0) || (c >= 0x1700 && c <= 0x170C) || (c >= 0x170E && c <= 0x1711) || (c >= 0x1720 && c <= 0x1731) || (c >= 0x1735 && c <= 0x1736) || (c >= 0x1740 && c <= 0x1751) || (c >= 0x1760 && c <= 0x176C) || (c >= 0x176E && c <= 0x1770) || (c >= 0x1780 && c <= 0x17B3) || (c == 0x17B6) || (c >= 0x17BE && c <= 0x17C5) || (c >= 0x17C7 && c <= 0x17C8) || (c >= 0x17D4 && c <= 0x17DA) || (c == 0x17DC) || (c >= 0x17E0 && c <= 0x17E9) || (c >= 0x1810 && c <= 0x1819) || (c >= 0x1820 && c <= 0x1877) || (c >= 0x1880 && c <= 0x18A8) || (c == 0x18AA) || (c >= 0x18B0 && c <= 0x18F5) || (c >= 0x1900 && c <= 0x191C) || (c >= 0x1923 && c <= 0x1926) || (c >= 0x1929 && c <= 0x192B) || (c >= 0x1930 && c <= 0x1931) || (c >= 0x1933 && c <= 0x1938) || (c >= 0x1946 && c <= 0x196D) || (c >= 0x1970 && c <= 0x1974) || (c >= 0x1980 && c <= 0x19AB) || (c >= 0x19B0 && c <= 0x19C9) || (c >= 0x19D0 && c <= 0x19DA) || (c >= 0x1A00 && c <= 0x1A16) || (c >= 0x1A19 && c <= 0x1A1B) || (c >= 0x1A1E && c <= 0x1A55) || (c == 0x1A57) || (c == 0x1A61) || (c >= 0x1A63 && c <= 0x1A64) || (c >= 0x1A6D && c <= 0x1A72) || (c >= 0x1A80 && c <= 0x1A89) || (c >= 0x1A90 && c <= 0x1A99) || (c >= 0x1AA0 && c <= 0x1AAD) || (c >= 0x1B04 && c <= 0x1B33) || (c == 0x1B35) || (c == 0x1B3B) || (c >= 0x1B3D && c <= 0x1B41) || (c >= 0x1B43 && c <= 0x1B4B) || (c >= 0x1B50 && c <= 0x1B6A) || (c >= 0x1B74 && c <= 0x1B7C) || (c >= 0x1B82 && c <= 0x1BA1) || (c >= 0x1BA6 && c <= 0x1BA7) || (c == 0x1BAA) || (c >= 0x1BAC && c <= 0x1BE5) || (c == 0x1BE7) || (c >= 0x1BEA && c <= 0x1BEC) || (c == 0x1BEE) || (c >= 0x1BF2 && c <= 0x1BF3) || (c >= 0x1BFC && c <= 0x1C2B) || (c >= 0x1C34 && c <= 0x1C35) || (c >= 0x1C3B && c <= 0x1C49) || (c >= 0x1C4D && c <= 0x1C7F) || (c >= 0x1CC0 && c <= 0x1CC7) || (c == 0x1CD3) || (c == 0x1CE1) || (c >= 0x1CE9 && c <= 0x1CEC) || (c >= 0x1CEE && c <= 0x1CF3) || (c >= 0x1CF5 && c <= 0x1CF6) || (c >= 0x1D00 && c <= 0x1DBF) || (c >= 0x1E00 && c <= 0x1F15) || (c >= 0x1F18 && c <= 0x1F1D) || (c >= 0x1F20 && c <= 0x1F45) || (c >= 0x1F48 && c <= 0x1F4D) || (c >= 0x1F50 && c <= 0x1F57) || (c == 0x1F59) || (c == 0x1F5B) || (c == 0x1F5D) || (c >= 0x1F5F && c <= 0x1F7D) || (c >= 0x1F80 && c <= 0x1FB4) || (c >= 0x1FB6 && c <= 0x1FBC) || (c == 0x1FBE) || (c >= 0x1FC2 && c <= 0x1FC4) || (c >= 0x1FC6 && c <= 0x1FCC) || (c >= 0x1FD0 && c <= 0x1FD3) || (c >= 0x1FD6 && c <= 0x1FDB) || (c >= 0x1FE0 && c <= 0x1FEC) || (c >= 0x1FF2 && c <= 0x1FF4) || (c >= 0x1FF6 && c <= 0x1FFC) || (c == 0x200E) || (c == 0x2071) || (c == 0x207F) || (c >= 0x2090 && c <= 0x209C) || (c == 0x2102) || (c == 0x2107) || (c >= 0x210A && c <= 0x2113) || (c == 0x2115) || (c >= 0x2119 && c <= 0x211D) || (c == 0x2124) || (c == 0x2126) || (c == 0x2128) || (c >= 0x212A && c <= 0x212D) || (c >= 0x212F && c <= 0x2139) || (c >= 0x213C && c <= 0x213F) || (c >= 0x2145 && c <= 0x2149) || (c >= 0x214E && c <= 0x214F) || (c >= 0x2160 && c <= 0x2188) || (c >= 0x2336 && c <= 0x237A) || (c == 0x2395) || (c >= 0x249C && c <= 0x24E9) || (c == 0x26AC) || (c >= 0x2800 && c <= 0x28FF) || (c >= 0x2C00 && c <= 0x2C2E) || (c >= 0x2C30 && c <= 0x2C5E) || (c >= 0x2C60 && c <= 0x2CE4) || (c >= 0x2CEB && c <= 0x2CEE) || (c >= 0x2CF2 && c <= 0x2CF3) || (c >= 0x2D00 && c <= 0x2D25) || (c == 0x2D27) || (c == 0x2D2D) || (c >= 0x2D30 && c <= 0x2D67) || (c >= 0x2D6F && c <= 0x2D70) || (c >= 0x2D80 && c <= 0x2D96) || (c >= 0x2DA0 && c <= 0x2DA6) || (c >= 0x2DA8 && c <= 0x2DAE) || (c >= 0x2DB0 && c <= 0x2DB6) || (c >= 0x2DB8 && c <= 0x2DBE) || (c >= 0x2DC0 && c <= 0x2DC6) || (c >= 0x2DC8 && c <= 0x2DCE) || (c >= 0x2DD0 && c <= 0x2DD6) || (c >= 0x2DD8 && c <= 0x2DDE) || (c >= 0x3005 && c <= 0x3007) || (c >= 0x3021 && c <= 0x3029) || (c >= 0x302E && c <= 0x302F) || (c >= 0x3031 && c <= 0x3035) || (c >= 0x3038 && c <= 0x303C) || (c >= 0x3041 && c <= 0x3096) || (c >= 0x309D && c <= 0x309F) || (c >= 0x30A1 && c <= 0x30FA) || (c >= 0x30FC && c <= 0x30FF) || (c >= 0x3105 && c <= 0x312D) || (c >= 0x3131 && c <= 0x318E) || (c >= 0x3190 && c <= 0x31BA) || (c >= 0x31F0 && c <= 0x321C) || (c >= 0x3220 && c <= 0x324F) || (c >= 0x3260 && c <= 0x327B) || (c >= 0x327F && c <= 0x32B0) || (c >= 0x32C0 && c <= 0x32CB) || (c >= 0x32D0 && c <= 0x32FE) || (c >= 0x3300 && c <= 0x3376) || (c >= 0x337B && c <= 0x33DD) || (c >= 0x33E0 && c <= 0x33FE) || (c == 0x3400) || (c == 0x4DB5) || (c == 0x4E00) || (c == 0x9FCC) || (c >= 0xA000 && c <= 0xA48C) || (c >= 0xA4D0 && c <= 0xA60C) || (c >= 0xA610 && c <= 0xA62B) || (c >= 0xA640 && c <= 0xA66E) || (c >= 0xA680 && c <= 0xA697) || (c >= 0xA6A0 && c <= 0xA6EF) || (c >= 0xA6F2 && c <= 0xA6F7) || (c >= 0xA722 && c <= 0xA787) || (c >= 0xA789 && c <= 0xA78E) || (c >= 0xA790 && c <= 0xA793) || (c >= 0xA7A0 && c <= 0xA7AA) || (c >= 0xA7F8 && c <= 0xA801) || (c >= 0xA803 && c <= 0xA805) || (c >= 0xA807 && c <= 0xA80A) || (c >= 0xA80C && c <= 0xA824) || (c == 0xA827) || (c >= 0xA830 && c <= 0xA837) || (c >= 0xA840 && c <= 0xA873) || (c >= 0xA880 && c <= 0xA8C3) || (c >= 0xA8CE && c <= 0xA8D9) || (c >= 0xA8F2 && c <= 0xA8FB) || (c >= 0xA900 && c <= 0xA925) || (c >= 0xA92E && c <= 0xA946) || (c >= 0xA952 && c <= 0xA953) || (c >= 0xA95F && c <= 0xA97C) || (c >= 0xA983 && c <= 0xA9B2) || (c >= 0xA9B4 && c <= 0xA9B5) || (c >= 0xA9BA && c <= 0xA9BB) || (c >= 0xA9BD && c <= 0xA9CD) || (c >= 0xA9CF && c <= 0xA9D9) || (c >= 0xA9DE && c <= 0xA9DF) || (c >= 0xAA00 && c <= 0xAA28) || (c >= 0xAA2F && c <= 0xAA30) || (c >= 0xAA33 && c <= 0xAA34) || (c >= 0xAA40 && c <= 0xAA42) || (c >= 0xAA44 && c <= 0xAA4B) || (c == 0xAA4D) || (c >= 0xAA50 && c <= 0xAA59) || (c >= 0xAA5C && c <= 0xAA7B) || (c >= 0xAA80 && c <= 0xAAAF) || (c == 0xAAB1) || (c >= 0xAAB5 && c <= 0xAAB6) || (c >= 0xAAB9 && c <= 0xAABD) || (c == 0xAAC0) || (c == 0xAAC2) || (c >= 0xAADB && c <= 0xAAEB) || (c >= 0xAAEE && c <= 0xAAF5) || (c >= 0xAB01 && c <= 0xAB06) || (c >= 0xAB09 && c <= 0xAB0E) || (c >= 0xAB11 && c <= 0xAB16) || (c >= 0xAB20 && c <= 0xAB26) || (c >= 0xAB28 && c <= 0xAB2E) || (c >= 0xABC0 && c <= 0xABE4) || (c >= 0xABE6 && c <= 0xABE7) || (c >= 0xABE9 && c <= 0xABEC) || (c >= 0xABF0 && c <= 0xABF9) || (c == 0xAC00) || (c == 0xD7A3) || (c >= 0xD7B0 && c <= 0xD7C6) || (c >= 0xD7CB && c <= 0xD7FB) || (c == 0xD800) || (c >= 0xDB7F && c <= 0xDB80) || (c >= 0xDBFF && c <= 0xDC00) || (c >= 0xDFFF && c <= 0xE000) || (c >= 0xF8FF && c <= 0xFA6D) || (c >= 0xFA70 && c <= 0xFAD9) || (c >= 0xFB00 && c <= 0xFB06) || (c >= 0xFB13 && c <= 0xFB17) || (c >= 0xFF21 && c <= 0xFF3A) || (c >= 0xFF41 && c <= 0xFF5A) || (c >= 0xFF66 && c <= 0xFFBE) || (c >= 0xFFC2 && c <= 0xFFC7) || (c >= 0xFFCA && c <= 0xFFCF) || (c >= 0xFFD2 && c <= 0xFFD7) || (c >= 0xFFDA && c <= 0xFFDC) || (c >= 0x10000 && c <= 0x1000B) || (c >= 0x1000D && c <= 0x10026) || (c >= 0x10028 && c <= 0x1003A) || (c >= 0x1003C && c <= 0x1003D) || (c >= 0x1003F && c <= 0x1004D) || (c >= 0x10050 && c <= 0x1005D) || (c >= 0x10080 && c <= 0x100FA) || (c == 0x10100) || (c == 0x10102) || (c >= 0x10107 && c <= 0x10133) || (c >= 0x10137 && c <= 0x1013F) || (c >= 0x101D0 && c <= 0x101FC) || (c >= 0x10280 && c <= 0x1029C) || (c >= 0x102A0 && c <= 0x102D0) || (c >= 0x10300 && c <= 0x1031E) || (c >= 0x10320 && c <= 0x10323) || (c >= 0x10330 && c <= 0x1034A) || (c >= 0x10380 && c <= 0x1039D) || (c >= 0x1039F && c <= 0x103C3) || (c >= 0x103C8 && c <= 0x103D5) || (c >= 0x10400 && c <= 0x1049D) || (c >= 0x104A0 && c <= 0x104A9) || (c == 0x11000) || (c >= 0x11002 && c <= 0x11037) || (c >= 0x11047 && c <= 0x1104D) || (c >= 0x11066 && c <= 0x1106F) || (c >= 0x11082 && c <= 0x110B2) || (c >= 0x110B7 && c <= 0x110B8) || (c >= 0x110BB && c <= 0x110C1) || (c >= 0x110D0 && c <= 0x110E8) || (c >= 0x110F0 && c <= 0x110F9) || (c >= 0x11103 && c <= 0x11126) || (c == 0x1112C) || (c >= 0x11136 && c <= 0x11143) || (c >= 0x11182 && c <= 0x111B5) || (c >= 0x111BF && c <= 0x111C8) || (c >= 0x111D0 && c <= 0x111D9) || (c >= 0x11680 && c <= 0x116AA) || (c == 0x116AC) || (c >= 0x116AE && c <= 0x116AF) || (c == 0x116B6) || (c >= 0x116C0 && c <= 0x116C9) || (c >= 0x12000 && c <= 0x1236E) || (c >= 0x12400 && c <= 0x12462) || (c >= 0x12470 && c <= 0x12473) || (c >= 0x13000 && c <= 0x1342E) || (c >= 0x16800 && c <= 0x16A38) || (c >= 0x16F00 && c <= 0x16F44) || (c >= 0x16F50 && c <= 0x16F7E) || (c >= 0x16F93 && c <= 0x16F9F) || (c >= 0x1B000 && c <= 0x1B001) || (c >= 0x1D000 && c <= 0x1D0F5) || (c >= 0x1D100 && c <= 0x1D126) || (c >= 0x1D129 && c <= 0x1D166) || (c >= 0x1D16A && c <= 0x1D172) || (c >= 0x1D183 && c <= 0x1D184) || (c >= 0x1D18C && c <= 0x1D1A9) || (c >= 0x1D1AE && c <= 0x1D1DD) || (c >= 0x1D360 && c <= 0x1D371) || (c >= 0x1D400 && c <= 0x1D454) || (c >= 0x1D456 && c <= 0x1D49C) || (c >= 0x1D49E && c <= 0x1D49F) || (c == 0x1D4A2) || (c >= 0x1D4A5 && c <= 0x1D4A6) || (c >= 0x1D4A9 && c <= 0x1D4AC) || (c >= 0x1D4AE && c <= 0x1D4B9) || (c == 0x1D4BB) || (c >= 0x1D4BD && c <= 0x1D4C3) || (c >= 0x1D4C5 && c <= 0x1D505) || (c >= 0x1D507 && c <= 0x1D50A) || (c >= 0x1D50D && c <= 0x1D514) || (c >= 0x1D516 && c <= 0x1D51C) || (c >= 0x1D51E && c <= 0x1D539) || (c >= 0x1D53B && c <= 0x1D53E) || (c >= 0x1D540 && c <= 0x1D544) || (c == 0x1D546) || (c >= 0x1D54A && c <= 0x1D550) || (c >= 0x1D552 && c <= 0x1D6A5) || (c >= 0x1D6A8 && c <= 0x1D6DA) || (c >= 0x1D6DC && c <= 0x1D714) || (c >= 0x1D716 && c <= 0x1D74E) || (c >= 0x1D750 && c <= 0x1D788) || (c >= 0x1D78A && c <= 0x1D7C2) || (c >= 0x1D7C4 && c <= 0x1D7CB) || (c >= 0x1F110 && c <= 0x1F12E) || (c >= 0x1F130 && c <= 0x1F169) || (c >= 0x1F170 && c <= 0x1F19A) || (c >= 0x1F1E6 && c <= 0x1F202) || (c >= 0x1F210 && c <= 0x1F23A) || (c >= 0x1F240 && c <= 0x1F248) || (c >= 0x1F250 && c <= 0x1F251) || (c == 0x20000) || (c == 0x2A6D6) || (c == 0x2A700) || (c == 0x2B734) || (c == 0x2B740) || (c == 0x2B81D) || (c >= 0x2F800 && c <= 0x2FA1D) || (c == 0xF0000) || (c == 0xFFFFD) || (c == 0x100000) || (c == 0x10FFFD);
}   

-(int)getBaseDirection {
  // Decode string into UTF32.
  NSData *utf32data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
  // NSUTF32StringEncoding has the platform's byte-order, which should
  // be the same as UTF32Char's.
  UTF32Char *utf32chars = (UTF32Char *)[utf32data bytes];

  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
    // UTF32 is a fixed-length encoding, so utf32chars[i] will
    // always give us the i'th character.
    if (isCodePointStrongRTL(utf32chars[i]))
      return -1;
    if (isCodePointStrongLTR(utf32chars[i]))
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

@end
```

## Longer answer: Generating the functions `isCodePointStrong{RTL,LTR}`

1. Create a script `hex_numbers_to_dec_ranges_py`,

   ```py
   import sys
   from itertools import groupby, count

   numberlist = []
   for line in sys.stdin:
       numberlist.append(int(line, 16));

   def as_range(iterable): # not sure how to do this part elegantly
       l = list(iterable)
       if len(l) > 1:
           return '(c >= 0x{0:X} && c <= 0x{1:X})'.format(l[0], l[-1])
       else:
           return '(c == 0x{0:X})'.format(l[0])

   print ' || '.join(as_range(g) for _, g in groupby(numberlist, lambda n, c=count(): n-next(c)))
   ```

   (code shamelessly stolen from [this excellent answer at StackExhange's Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5202)).
2. Run from a terminal:

   ```bsh
   curl http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt > /tmp/UnicodeData.txt
   cat /tmp/UnicodeData.txt | awk -F';' '$5 == "R" || $5 == "AL"' | cut -d';' -f1 | python hex_numbers_to_dec_ranges.py > rtl.m
   cat /tmp/UnicodeData.txt | awk -F';' '$5 == "L"' | cut -d';' -f1 | python hex_numbers_to_dec_ranges.py > ltr.m
   rm /tmp/UnicodeData.txt
   ```

---

**EDIT:** As @masmor correctly noted, the `for` loop in `getBaseDirection` scans characters, and not bytes. Therefore, it should terminate after "character" number of iterations, and not "bytes" number of iterations. In other words, `self.length` times and not `utf32data.length` times. The code is now corrected.

Comment: I've been using this code but with the latest compiler I started getting lots of warnings that some of these comparisons would **always** return false:  `return ... (c >= 0x10800 && c <= 0x10805)...`.  This is because `unichar` is `unsigned short` which has a maximum value of 0xFFFF and these constants are larger than that.  Where do these constants come from?  Maybe I should create a new question?

Comment: Hmmm... it appears that `unichar` represents a UTF-16 character, while the data I parsed describes Unicode code points (whose range requires 32 bits per code point). So my code might get the wrong result for strings with Unicode surrogates (characters which require more than `unichar` to represent). The code should be modified to take surrogates into account; I might get to it during the weekend.

Comment: any suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: Warnings addressed as far as I know (I couldn't make my XCode spit out warnings), and scanning function corrected. If it's unclear what was the fix, let me know.

Comment: That works perfectly.  Nice update!  BTW, I only get the warnings with XCode 5.

Answer (score 2):

I think the scan loop in `-getBaseDirection` should be for `self.length` times instead of `utf32data.length` in the accepted answer.

`utf32data.length` is the size in bytes while `sizeof(UTF32Char) == 4`, which would result in an overrun.

In action, the current code sporadically returns false positives for identical input, depending on what it overruns onto (maybe it'll segfault on a sufficiently bad day). Everything else seems to be working perfectly with the fix.

Comment: You're right! I'll fix the answer. But, this should not be an answer; could you move it into a comment?

Comment: I see you've already tried to make this edit once - my bad for missing it, and thanks for not giving up :)

Comment: Yes, I guess it was rejected for trying to edit your code. Commenting was my initial thought but sadly I don't have enough rep... Still new to the contributing side of SO!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 this can be done by applying dir="auto" to the element. It's implemented in WebKit, though I'm not completely sure that it's available in iOS.

dir="auto" is very simple, and you can probably implement it yourself - just search for the first character that has strong directionality, and apply its directionality to the whole thing.

If you can't find anything in iOS, you can try to take some smarter ideas from the way StatusNet implemented it: http://status.net/sites/default/files/issues/1346_jquery.directionDetector.js

Comment: That's actually a good idea - just look examine the first character. I guess there are tables that specify this, but the question is if there is anything already written in c/objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that is based on the [language detection of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring).

Method returns `NSTextAlignmentNatural` if direction can not be identified.

```
@implementation NSString (StringAlignmentDetection)

- (NSTextAlignment)naturalTextAligment
{
    NSArray *tagschemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, nil];
    NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:tagschemes options:0];
    [tagger setString:self];
    NSString *language = [tagger tagAtIndex:0 scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage tokenRange:NULL sentenceRange:NULL];

    NSTextAlignment alignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;

    if(!language)
    {
        return alignment;
    }

    NSLocaleLanguageDirection direction = [NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage: language];

    switch (direction)
    {
        case NSLocaleLanguageDirectionLeftToRight:
            alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            break;

        case NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft:
            alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            break;

        default:
            alignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
            break;
    }

    return alignment;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/home) offers methods for what you are trying to achieve and on Xcode 11 it is possible to link the ICU library into an iOS application or iOS framework target. To do so, open your target and on the "General" tab under "Frameworks and Libraries" add `libicucore.tbd`.

[image: Adding libicucore in Xcode]

It might happen that Xcode chooses the macOS variant of the library if you do that in which case you'll see something like this in your project file.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX /* libicucore.tbd */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = "sourcecode.text-based-dylib-definition"; name = libicucore.tbd; path = Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.tbd; sourceTree = DEVELOPER_DIR; };
```

To force the iOS variant, simply edit the project file with a text editor to make the line look something like this

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX /* libicucore.tbd */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = "sourcecode.text-based-dylib-definition"; name = libicucore.tbd; path = usr/lib/libicucore.tbd; sourceTree = SDKROOT; };
```

Unfortunately, the version of the library that ships with iOS is a bit older and doesn't include `ubidi_getBaseDirection`. There is, however, a method `u_charDirection` that you can use to rebuilt `ubidi_getBaseDirection`. Simply walk the characters in the string and return the direction of the first character with strong directionality. Below is an example of how to do this in Swift (Objective-C port should be straightforward).

```
enum Direction {
    case leftToRight
    case rightToLeft
    case neutral
}

func ubidi_getBaseDirection(of string: String) -> Direction {
    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf32) else {
        return .leftToRight
    }
    let chars = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.bindMemory(to: UChar32.self) }
    for c in chars {
        let direction = u_charDirection(c)
        if direction == U_RIGHT_TO_LEFT || direction == U_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC {
            return .rightToLeft
        } else if direction == U_LEFT_TO_RIGHT {
            return .leftToRight
        }
    }
    return .neutral
}
```

Note that since `libicucore` is a pure C library, you'll need to add it to your bridging header / umbrella header if you're working in Swift. I've found the following to be enough.

```
#include "unicode/utypes.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Update

You can use `NLLanguageRecognizer` available since since iOS 12:

```swift
import NaturalLanguage

extension String {
    var isRightToLeft: Bool {
        guard let language = NLLanguageRecognizer.dominantLanguage(for: self) else {
            return false
        }

        switch language {
        case .arabic, .hebrew, .persian, .urdu:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```