# Detect actual text direction in NSString or NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, unicode, nsattributedstring, right-to-left

#### Question

Is there a definitive way to detect if the text direction in `NSString` or `NSAttributedString` is right-to-left? Text is received from external resource, not entered in the app (can't use `UITextInput` protocol methods).

#### Bad solution

I have been detecting it using `CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage()` and then `+[NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:]`, but it is pretty unreliable for strings, where there are only a few arabic characters and many latin. They are processes as a RTL when displayed in the label, but incorrect direction detection makes inconsistent behaviour.

#### Investigation

During development, I have found out that when creating `NSAttributedString` with no attributes except for the font and displaying it using `TTTAttributedLabel`, RTL text aligns to the right edge. When using simple `NSString`, or when using standard `UILabel` with attributed string, alignment stays left.
So, there has to be something in the text that says "it is RTL" and there is some method to detect it.

I analysed what I am receiving from server, and there were no standard Unicode bidi chars. This is how it looks. JSON is sent in ascii with all unicode characters escaped:

```
"\u0643\u062a\u0628\u062a \u0648\u0648\u062c\u0650 .."
```

When unescaping, it looks like this, with `\u0643` is on the far right before the dots:

```
"كتبت ووجِ .."
```

As far as I can tell, every character represents a single character in arabic language, and there are no `U+202B` or similar control characters which could be used to easily detect direction.

Yet, when rendering this text through `TTTAttributedLabel`, it aligns right. I started looking into the [source code](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel), and it doesn't do anything to detect the direction or set the alignment. It only created the framesetter using `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString()` and then, when it gets lines from it using `CTFrameGetLines()` and line positions with `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()`, they are already aligned to the right.

So, does anyone know if direction can be detected solely from the text with publicly available (and preferably fast) API methods?

Comment: Refer this link it solve your problem [Automatically align text in UILabel according to text language][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397137/automatically-align-text-in-uilabel-according-to-text-language

Answer (score 0):

Check This link that helps to you [Automatically align text in UILabel according to text language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397137/automatically-align-text-in-uilabel-according-to-text-language)

Change this for right and left alignment

```
      if (isCodePointStrongRTL(utf32chars[i]))
            return 2;
        if (isCodePointStrongLTR(utf32chars[i]))
            return 0;
```

Comment: I was thinking about just hardcoding all the RTL char ranges, but I sort of hope there is either an easier or at least embedded into the framework way.

Answer (score 0):

saw this comment on other question, and thought it's important for others to check this out. this was exactly what I was looking for RTL-LTR :

"
but I've been using a solution to explicitly set the direction based on known RTL languages, which used this as a starting point:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309559
"